# WordPress Header Text Random Hover Color

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

My heading for WordPress is using the blog name.

I think this is the code in WordPress that displays the header text:

```
 <a id="logo" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" <?php echo $logo_class; ?>>
```

I can change header text using the below CCS code:

```
header#top #logo {}
```

I want to change it so text to randomize on hover.
Similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/neeklamy/3eXfk/

Any ideas how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see any difficulty. Where do you stuck ? *text to randomize on hover* ?

Comment: You want to randomize color on each hover or on each page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```js
var colors = ['#f9c213', '#f35c4a', '#3da1bf', '#827287'];
var originalcolor = $('#logo').css('color');

$('#logo').on('mouseenter', function(){
  var col2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  
  var newcolor = colors[col2];
  console.log(newcolor); 
  $(this).css('color',newcolor);
});

$('#logo').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).css('color', originalcolor);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="logo" href="#" class="">Link</a>
```

Comment: Where exactly do I add that code? I tried adding it into the header.php file but didn't work.